# how to create Jqgrid treetableusing java/servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets, jqgrid

I want to create tree table with 3-4 hierarchical structure, for that i have 4-5 queries and my database doesn't have any mapping relation between the data that's why i am facing issues, i just saw this  [This is like what i want to build a tree table hierarchy](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#) i just want to make tree table like this.The one Hierarchy->Load sub grid data only once.I want like this one.But i don't have any knowledge in PHP So can anyone here help me out please.
And i don't have any mapping in my database or any relation I just want to create this tree table using query result.

Please anyone here guide me how can i achieve this.

I can convert one query result in to JSON object using map and list,But i don't know how to return result from multiple queries in to JSONObject, If i ll be able to achieve this then i can parse the data into html page using j query or java script.
So anyone out there have some knowledge please help me out.

Comment: Is there anyone to help me or guide me ?

Comment: Please tell me how to loop various queries result according to 3 level hierarchy.I just don't know to to pass two queries result in a json format using java